# Characteristic Polynomial of Endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space with basis $B = (v_1,\ v_2,\ v_3,\ v_4)$ and $f \in End(V)$ with $$f(v_i) = v_{i+1},\ \ \ f(v_4) := v_1$$ Calculate the characteristic polynomial $P_f(t)$ of $f$.

I know that 
$$P_f(t) = P_A(t)$$

where $A := M^B_B(f)$ the transformation matrix. Then since the matrix is triangular M_B^B(f) = \begin{pmatrix} B & * \\ 0 & B' \end{pmatrix} we would have
$$P_f(t) = P_B(t)P_{B'}(t)$$
Performing Gaussian Elimination over the columns of $B'$ - 4 swaps, would transform $B'$ into $B$ and not affect the sign of the determinant, so 
$$P_f(t) = P_B(t)^2$$
$$P_f(t) = (t^4 - a_1t^3 + a_2t^2 + a_1t + a_4)^2$$

And how to proceed in order to fully *calculate* $P_f(t)$? Was so far correct? Any remarks?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $B'$? And why don't you simple write out what $A$ is and compute the characteristic polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** What is $f^4(v_i)$? What does that tell you about the characteristic polynomial of $f$?

Alternatively you could simply write out $f$ on the basis $B$; it is simply
$$M_B^B(f)=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix},$$
so computing the characteristic polynomial is routine.

Comment: So for $f^4$ would be $id$, which has $A = I_4$, so $P_{f^4}(t)= P_{I_4}(t)$ will be $(t-1)^4$. Then for $f$ will be only $t-1$?

Comment: How do you conclude that $P_f(t)=t-1$? The characteristic polynomial is of degree $4$. The fact that $f^4=\operatorname{id}$ already tells you that $f$ is a root of $X^4-I$, so that must be its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Servaes The fact that $f$ satisfies $X^4-1$ does not yield the characteristic polynomial of $f$, even if we know its of degree $4$. For example the characteristic polynomial could still be $(X^2-1)^2$. You need another argument, namely the fact that $v_1, f(v_1), f^2(v_1), f^3(v_1)$ are linear independent, in particular the minimal polynomial is of degree at least $4$. Thus $X^4-1$ IS the minimal polynomial and then it follows that it is equal to the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @MooS You are absolutely right, my previous comment was overly brief. One should check that $f$ is not a root of any divisor of $X^4-1$, i.e. that $f$ is not a root of $X^2-1$ or $X^2+1$. And then indeed one needs a theorem like [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem), for example.